# Angular material: refresh cdkDropListConnectedTo while already dragging?

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop

I need to refresh the connected dropLists after dragging has already started, because some dropLists are rendered after hovering over some folded sections of my menu. So i'm basicly doing this:

```
[cdkDropListConnectedTo]="dropZones | async"
```

But it seems that it's not refreshed for a drag process that's already started. I've also tried using cdkDropListEnterPredicate, but without success.

Comment: why not use cdkDropListGroup https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#transferring-items-between-lists ? So any cdkDropList in the group can be dragged

Comment: will consider cdkDropLists that are rendered after dragging has started?

Comment: I'm afraid that not if you use *ngIf, but I think that the response is yes if use display:none